# Cronjob - Truenas File backup - Linux file copy command

Tags: cron, copy, backup, cp

I'm runnning a Truenas server with my video files along my workstation in my video editing studio. Connection between them is 10gb, but even so, it is worse than editing video files on a drive local to the workstation.

My plan is:

1.Copy new files from SD Cards to my workstations nvme drive, and work with them locally.

2.Setup a cron job on my truenas to copy all the new/modified files in the workstation NVME drive to a pool in the Truenas daily. I need to just copy and keep adding files, not "sync", because:

3.When the NVME is full, I can just delete any folder in it to free space, knowing that it was copied to the Truenas and remains there for use if I need them in the future.

For that I need to write the right cp command for the cronjob, which I was unsucessfull with.

I'm open to other solutions for the problem ;)

I've tried different arguments for the cp command, but it didn't work as expected. Either directories where duplicated or not copied at all.

There is also the problem of modified files, which I don't know how to filter, so to not just overwrite everything all the time.

Comment: Nice idea, but here we are not a coding service. We will help you when you got stuck with *your* code. — Please update your question with some code and results to see where your problem is.